# Aggregating rows from a condition in a linking table in SQL

Tags: sql-server, aggregate, window-functions

I am having trouble wrapping my head around a query that gives me these results

I have a table that gives me Devices uses per day.

dbo.DailyUses

```
Uses |   Date   |  Device
3    | 2020-3-1 |    A2
5    | 2020-3-1 |    B3
1    | 2020-3-2 |    A2
12   | 2020-3-3 |    C4
```

I have another table gives me the possible ErrorCodes of each devices.

dbo.Code_SKU_Combos

```
ErrorCode |  Device
   12.24  |    A2
   12.25  |    A2
   12.26  |    A2
   12.24  |    B3
   12.26  |    B3
   12.25  |    C4
```

With those two tables, I want to get how much uses per day did each "errorcode cable devices" where used

Example Output

```
Uses |   Date   |  ErrorCode
8    | 2020-3-1 |    12.24
3    | 2020-3-1 |    12.25
8    | 2020-3-1 |    12.26
5    | 2020-3-2 |    12.24
5    | 2020-3-2 |    12.25
5    | 2020-3-2 |    12.26
0    | 2020-3-3 |    12.24
12   | 2020-3-3 |    12.25
0    | 2020-3-3 |    12.26
```

I was thinking of using window functions or join, but the fact that the two tables will be using repeating values just confuses me on creating Partitions and Group By. I feel like I am over thinking it.

I created a cross table of my date range and Error Codes, now I just need to create a SUM() function that looks at dbo.DailyUses based on a filter created from dbo.Code_Sku_Combos

Also I am using Microsoft SQL

Comment: It seems there's a missing info on the `dbo.Code_SKU_Combos` table: a date to refer to the day that error code happened, otherwise, if the only relation between those two tables is the device, you won't be able to group the results by date for every device from `dbo.DailyUses` will aggregate every row for that device on `dbo.Code_SKU_Combos` and you'll have a bunch of rows with the same result number.

Comment: I see how this may have been confusing. We are not looking at the day the errorcode happened, but rather how many times the a group of devices were used , in which that group of devices is capable of throwing that error. 

This is to help me normalize another table of error counts

Comment: I think I still don't get it. Is the output table you provided a result of only the values on the sample tables? shouldn't this value: `5    | 2020-3-1 |    12.25` be `3    | 2020-3-1 |    12.25` since error code 12.25 is not possible for B3?

Comment: I am very sorry for the type, you would be correct. The output table is only a result of the two input tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution can be :

The first select gets all combination of date and error combination that exist in the tables.

If  you actually want all possible Dates, you need to add another created table, with all possiible dates

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Code_SKU_Combos
>     ([ErrorCode] varchar(5), [Device] varchar(2))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO Code_SKU_Combos
>     ([ErrorCode], [Device])
> VALUES
>     ('12.24', 'A2'),
>     ('12.25', 'A2'),
>     ('12.26', 'A2'),
>     ('12.24', 'B3'),
>     ('12.26', 'B3'),
>     ('12.25', 'C4')
> ;
> GO
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE DailyUses
>     ([Uses] int, [Date] Date, [Device] varchar(2))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO DailyUses
>     ([Uses], [Date], [Device])
> VALUES
>     (3, '2020-3-1', 'A2'),
>     (5, '2020-3-1', 'B3'),
>     (1, '2020-3-2', 'A2'),
>     (12, '2020-3-3', 'C4')
> ;
> GO
> ```

> ```
> SELECT DISTINCT [Date],[ErrorCode] FROM DailyUses CROSS JOIN  Code_SKU_Combos
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Date       | ErrorCode
> :--------- | :--------
> 2020-03-01 | 12.24    
> 2020-03-01 | 12.25    
> 2020-03-01 | 12.26    
> 2020-03-02 | 12.24    
> 2020-03-02 | 12.25    
> 2020-03-02 | 12.26    
> 2020-03-03 | 12.24    
> 2020-03-03 | 12.25    
> 2020-03-03 | 12.26
> ```

> ```
> SELECT ISNULL (SUM([Uses]),0) AS Uses, DateComp as [Date],[errorcomp] AS ErrorCode
> FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [Date] as DateComp,[ErrorCode] AS errorcomp FROM DailyUses CROSS JOIN  Code_SKU_Combos) t1
> LEFT JOIN (
> DailyUses d INNER JOIN Code_SKU_Combos c ON d.[Device] = c.[Device]) ON t1.DateComp = d.[Date] 
> AND  t1.errorcomp = c.[ErrorCode]
>
> GROUP BY [DateComp],[errorcomp]
> ORDER BY [DateComp],[errorcomp]
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Uses | Date       | ErrorCode
> ---: | :--------- | :--------
>    8 | 2020-03-01 | 12.24    
>    3 | 2020-03-01 | 12.25    
>    8 | 2020-03-01 | 12.26    
>    1 | 2020-03-02 | 12.24    
>    1 | 2020-03-02 | 12.25    
>    1 | 2020-03-02 | 12.26    
>    0 | 2020-03-03 | 12.24    
>   12 | 2020-03-03 | 12.25    
>    0 | 2020-03-03 | 12.26
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a2dd1fc245cb924f3cbde27baefb6f28)*

Comment: Thank You! Ill let you know if it works out after my 30 minutes query finishes

Comment: Worked like a charm, Thank You for your time